# Generic way to make a template on nested typename

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Motivation:

Given a class hierarchy (and using CRTP technique with mixin tp. classes, but it is omitted here for the sake of simplicity), I would like to generically address a nested type with a known identifier, but possibly with "unknown" parent classes.

Minimal example with my first (unsuccessful) attempt:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    using Type_x = int;
    using Type_y = char;
};

struct B {
    using Type_x = float;
    using Type_y = double;
};

template <typename T> struct C {
    using Type_x = typename T::Type_x;
    using Type_y = typename T::Type_y;
};

// not possible
// template <typename T, typename U> using Tp_type = typename T::typename U;
//
// static_assert(is_same_v<C<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<C<A>, Type_x>>);
```

I came up with a workaround solution, which seems to be functional, but is not too pretty.
Here is an example where a derived class also introduces further nested type, but it is still handled in a quite generic way:

```cpp
/// given the code above ...

struct None {};

constexpr int type_x_id = 1;
constexpr int type_y_id = 2;

template <typename T>
struct D1 : C<T> {
    using typename C<T>::Type_x;
    using typename C<T>::Type_y;

    template <int typeId>
        using Type = conditional_t<typeId == type_x_id, Type_x,
                     conditional_t<typeId == type_y_id, Type_y,
                     None>>;
};

constexpr int type_z_id = 3;

template <typename T>
struct D2 : D1<T> {
    using Type_z = long;

    template <int typeId>
        using Type = conditional_t<!is_same_v<typename D1<T>::template Type<typeId>, None>,
                                   typename D1<T>::template Type<typeId>,
                     conditional_t<typeId == type_z_id, Type_z,
                     None>>;
};

template <typename T, int typeId> using Tp_type = typename T::template Type<typeId>;
```

Usage/tests:

```cpp
static_assert(is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D1<A>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D1<A>, type_y_id>>);
// static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D1<A>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D1<A>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D1<A>, type_y_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D1<A>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D2<A>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D2<A>, type_y_id>>);
// static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D2<A>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D2<A>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D2<A>, type_y_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D2<A>, type_z_id>>);

static_assert(is_same_v<D1<B>::Type_x, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D1<B>::Type_y, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_y_id>>);
// static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<B>::Type_z, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<B>::Type_x, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<B>::Type_y, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_y_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D2<B>::Type_z, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D1<B>::Type_x, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D1<B>::Type_y, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_y_id>>);
// static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<B>::Type_z, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<B>::Type_x, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<B>::Type_y, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_y_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<B>::Type_z, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_z_id>>);

static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_y_id>>);
// static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_y_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D1<B>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_y_id>>);
// static_assert(!is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_z_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_x, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_x_id>>);
static_assert(!is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_y, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_y_id>>);
static_assert(is_same_v<D2<A>::Type_z, Tp_type<D2<B>, type_z_id>>);
```

Is there a better solution? For example, a one that would not require to define `Type` every time a new nested type identifier comes along.

Comment: I don't get the minimal example. you want a template working on names and it simply would not work.

Comment: The minimal example contains my unsuccessful attempt how to do the work. I guess that there is no direct way to address the nested type itself, without a full qualification. But I'm not sure..

Comment: You cannot pass **name** as template parameter. you might have MACRO: `#define Tp_type(Class, Type) = typename Class::Type`. Not sure of what you want...

Comment: If it fulfill your needs, you can use compile time strings instead of the name. As this you can create compile time arrays of times indexed by compile time strings. No idea if that helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass names around and look up types based on them without writing entire libraries or using compile-time reflection (which looks like [c++26](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b26) at this point).

But you want to be able to pass around identifiers at compile time.  Your `int` solution is a bit awkward; I'd suggest passing around templates that do the lookup:

```
template<class T>
using Type_x_t = typename T::Type_x;
template<class T>
using Type_y_t = typename T::Type_y;
```

etc

Then you can do:

```
template <typename T, template<class...> class U_t>
using Tp_type_t = U_t<T>;

static_assert(
  std::is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_x, Tp_type_t<D1<A>, Type_x_t>);
);
```

or:

```
static_assert(
  std::is_same_v<D1<A>::Type_x, Type_x_t<D1<A>>);
);
```

We pass around template `Foo_t<>` that maps `T` to `T::Foo`, then that acts as a "name" for a subtype.